# How to edit/append a cell value based on date range?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-dates

I have a list of dates (including previous, current, and future weeks) and there is a number associated with each date. Example:

[image]

I want to add 'x' in front of all the values belonging to dates from previous or future weeks. Only values associated with dates from the current week should remain unchanged (i.e. without 'x'). Also, this should get updated automatically as the date shifts to next week and so on. So considering the current week's date range is from Mon, Jul 4 to Fri, Jul 8 - the expected output should look like this:

[image]

Any help/suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

this should solve your problem:

```
=IF(WEEKNUM(TODAY())=WEEKNUM(A1),B1,CONCAT("x",B1))
```

*(try this in column c)*